# Add object other than string to ToolStripDropDownButton DropDownItem

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripdropdown

It's easy to add strings to a ToolStripDropDownButton as a new DropDownItem. What I need is to add a custom object to the DropDownItems so that I can assign a key/value like object to the DropDownItem.

How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ToolStripItems can only display text and images and don't take objects.  You can try sneaking  an object in the Tag property of the button:

```
  ToolStripDropDownButton b = new ToolStripDropDownButton();
  b.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripButton("Hello") { Tag = new Something() });
```

and then when you handle the click event, inspect the Tag property for your object.

Comment: Thanks. As I only need an ID and the text, putting an int into the Tag will suffice.